# Rear suspension looks funny after axle replacement

Tags: suspension, axle, skoda

I have just had the rear axle replaced for my Skoda Roomster. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ7o2.jpg) is how it looks now; another photo can be found below.

I have an impression that the rear suspension now looks different than it used to. I am not quite sure as I do not have any photos of the original situation, but I found a [press photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcrsu.jpg) from a decent angle, though from a bit far away.

My concern is that the spring seat (?; the thing that the spring rests on) is so **low to the ground** (I measured merely 10 centimetres) and is **slant** (not horizontal). Both sides look roughly symmetric; the left side that is in the photo is perhaps a bit more slant than the right side, but I could be wrong; I have not measured the angles. The suspension coming so low to the ground, I am afraid of hitting a stone all too easily when driving on a gravel road.

**Q:** Is that how it should be, or should I indeed be concerned?

**Update:** I have found [here](https://www.car.info/en-se/skoda/roomster/specs) that ground clearance of Skoda Roomster is supposed to be 14 centimetres. I am not entirely sure whether spring seats count in measuring ground clearance (there is [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/69714) though). But if they do, then this seems to be an indication that the spring seats are indeed too low (by approximately 4 centimetres), in line with my visual perception.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I did not manage to crop the photo.

Comment: Are both sides the same?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, yes, they are roughly the same. Both are slant and both are low to the ground.

Answer (score 2):

The difference may be due to the angle you are looking at.  Try taking a photograph of the rear of the car that matches the press photo (same distance and angle) and see what difference that makes.  Also bear in mind that some press photos will be of pre-production cars.

Looking at [this](https://workshop-manuals.com/skoda/roomster/chassis/rear_suspension_drive_shaft/rear_axle_with_drum_brake/) diagram, I'd say the measure I'd personally apply would be that the spring seat (shown labelled 25) is horizontal.  It may be that the design of the rear beam is such that the spring seat is horizontal but the pickup point for it is angled inwards.  I think the real measure is, is there any adjustment or alternative ways to fit the rear beam that would prevent this?

I supposed the ideal way to be sure would be to either ask a Skoda qualified mechanic their opinion or to find another Roomster for comparison.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I posted the question is case someone might find the answer to be obvious. Otherwise, I am planning to take it back to a workshop. Just maybe another one to get an independent, unbiased evaluation.

Comment: I wonder if parts 34 / 35 (the stone guard) is what you're seeing hanging down?

Comment: That could well be them, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please see my update at the end of the post. I make an argument for why the spring seats are too low by about 4 centimetres. Does my reasoning make sense? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That looks about right from the different cars I've worked on.

The 4" clearance is running next to the wheel so it is assumed by the designers that the wheel will be in contact with ground before any part of the suspension will.
In reality if you live up an unmade road with some washed out pot holes then you quickly find out how much clearance you really need.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. My main concern is the difference between before and after the rear axle change. Unfortunately I cannot compare directly as I have not documented the situation before the change. I would rather first detect trouble in theory and prevent it than experience it in practice once the suspension has already been damaged. I posted the question is case someone might find the answer to be obvious. Otherwise, I am planning to take it back to a workshop. Just maybe another one to get an independent, unbiased evaluation.

Comment: Please see my update at the end of the post. I make an argument for why the spring seats are too low by about 4 centimetres. Does my reasoning make sense? Thank you.